# Python list values are getting overriden

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a scenario where a python utility will inquire case ID dependencies for a case ID from a databae. Let's assume case ID 123 has dependency on case IDs 234 and 456.

There are two lists. r2 will hold empty or 1 or more than one values (dependent case ids). In turn each case ID will have versions like v1, v2, etc, and these are appended to list r3. Patch 123 will be deployed only if all versions of a case ID are deployed.

```
r2 = [187045, 187046] 
r3 = []
```

I fetch these version values from a DB log table. Everything is working fine except that a small bug is causing a problem. r3[] is getting over-ridden with new values.

```
for item in r2:
        cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
        row3 = cursor.fetchall()  #fetches a tuple
        thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]  #converts tuple to a list
        r3 = list(map(int, thi_tuple)) #converts list to list of ints
        print(r3)
```

the output is as follows

```
[2, 3] #versions of 187045
[1] #version of 187046
```

And the final output of `r3` is just `[1]`. How to get `r3 = [2, 3 ,1]`?

I know that the for loop is over-riding the list with iteration.

Regards

Comment: each iteration of `r2` of you are initialize `r3`  here: `r3 = list(map(int, thi_tuple)) #converts list to list of ints `that why you have 1 value each time , you need to init you array before the loot and append to it, but can you provdie , a print of (row3) and what you expected i will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have

```
for item in r2:
    cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
    row3 = cursor.fetchall()  #fetches a tuple
    thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]  #converts tuple to a list
    r3 = list(map(int, thi_tuple)) #converts list to list of ints
    print(r3)
```

replace with

```
for item in r2:
    cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
    row3 = cursor.fetchall()  #fetches a tuple
    thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]  #converts tuple to a list
    r3 += list(map(int, thi_tuple)) # append new values
    print(r3)
```

Comment: Thank bro! It worked. I tried `r3.append(list(map(int, thi_tuple)))`...it is creating list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it will solve your problem.
Insted of

```
r3 = list(map(int, thi_tuple))
```

Use

```
r3 = r3 + list(map(int, thi_tuple))
```

You loop will now look like this:

```
for item in r2:
    cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
    row3 = cursor.fetchall()  # fetches a tuple
    thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]  # converts tuple to a list
    r3 = r3 + list(map(int, thi_tuple))  # converts list to list of ints
    print(r3)
```